# Why was Ayiana left behind?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

In Stargate the Ancient Ayiana plays the role of the first Ancient to be discovered by the SGC. In the first episode of Atlantis she is seen staying behind while the rest of the Ancients leave in Atlantis. She does not appear to be infected during this scene as she can be seen with another Ancient who does not appear to have any sort of containment equipment on.

My question is why was she left behind? Was she in fact infected and left behind for this reason or did she become she become infected at a later time?

Comment: infected by what? the ancients were under attack from the wraith, not an infection

Comment: The plague was the reason why they created the time machine seen in the episode Window of Opportunity. It ultimately wiped out many colonies and forced them to either ascend or leave the galaxy around 5-10M years ago.

Comment: @himarm - the scene described in the question is of the Ancients leaving Earth in Atlantis to travel to the Pegasus galaxy.

Comment: Ayana was infected by plague, which was why she was left behind on Earth when the city took off.  Since she's standing in the snow, the implication is that she is frozen pretty quickly (to be thawed out by the good folks at White Rock in SG1 Season Six), so she would have had no chance to become infected after the city left.

It's implied that the Ori, whom the Ancients had fled and were still fleeing, were responsible for the plague which required the Ancients to scour all life from the Milky Way Galaxy and restart it again with the Dakara Device, but this is never explicitly stated in canon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- We honestly do not know
- The ancient left behind did not necessarily have an infection.

So firstly that is a plot hole that we will never likely be able to fill. The series was cancelled (which I am happy to report I saw some mention of a new movie adaptation of some sort in the works...)

But just because she had some "contagion" does not mean that she had an infection that was deadly or dangerous to her fellow ancients. The only reason that everyone got infected from her is because humanity had never dealt with "that" before. It is possible that what she had was the equivalent of the common cold to the ancients. She was able to heal it pretty easily and showed no real signs of self danger. If anything she was just a carrier.

As has already been mentioned the plague the ancients were combatting was the Wraith; remember that we believe the wraith are evolved from ancients that were infected by the wraith/iratus bug. That plague spread across their new galaxy and the ancients ascended to escape it... (basically said screw you to two universes and then of course punished anyone that tried to help out...)

As far as the ancient left behind anything is possible. We know that the ancients just up and decided to move "along from our region of space long ago." As far as we know it was not out of fear or anything, just simple curiosity.

It is interesting that she was enclosed within the block of ice that sustained her. To know why she was left behind we would need to know that. Whether that is some form of cryo-containment or just an innate ability the ancients possessed, similar to Teal'k being able to survive underwater for a short time, we do not and will likely never know. Without knowing the circumstances behind why she was frozen in the first place we won't ever have a chance of answering that question.

Comment: It's interesting to note that in the first episode of Atlantis we see two ancients standing face to face, one of which looks like Ayiana.  The other ancient walks away from her and then we see Atlantis lift off.  http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ayiana lists her as appearing in Rising and the IMDB page also credits that name.  This seems to imply that it really was Ayiana in that first scene, and that she was purposely left behind (or decided to stay behind) for some reason.  Though how and why she ended up in a block of ice is anyone's guess.

Comment: I agree. The other thing I was thinking about the other day as well since watching the entire series over (I am on season ten now) is that it is interesting how much the ancients moved around.

Comment: So first they evolved on Earth, joined up with the fantastic four, and then took off. Then they essentially create the wraith and abandon the galaxy by either coming back to the Milky Way, ascending, or hanging out with new humans on Earth. And of course, where I am in the series they are abandoning life in the Milky Way to the Ori (which they pretty much created as well...). Basically they just screw stuff up everywhere they go and then abandon everybody by looking out for numero uno... haha

Comment: Not quite.  They evolved in another galaxy.  Due to a philosophical difference they (the Alterans) left to eventually come to Earth while their fundamentalist brethren (The Ori) remained behind.  The Alterans/Ancients then build the stargates and seeded the Milky Way (and it seems implied that they created the alliance around this point).  They then went to Pegasus and seeded that galaxy too, but fell prey to the Iratus bug which is what created the Wraith (Alteran/Iratus hybrid).  They then escaped back to the Milky way to live out their days and ascend.  After ascension they...

Comment: ...shielded us from the Ori, but refused to intervene in mortal affairs due to their belief in free will (though you're right that they should have cleaned up the Wraith mess that they left behind).  Several of them still took part in the fight against the Ori though (Orlin, Moros/Meerdin/Merlin, Morgan, etc) and paid dearly for it.  Much of this is clarified in the Ark of Truth, which was a great movie...if you ignore all the replicator melodrama...

Comment: I'm not so sure about that because one of the first episodes of Atlantis was of that black mist escaping within the city and McKay says the research is the first indication the Ancients researched ascension. With the device and research in the Pegasus galaxy it means they split after being there... Although I will have to go back and rewatch Ark of Truth, that one has been a while...

Comment: I always assumed that they were researching ascension in Pegasus, but that research was still in progress when the Wraith laid siege to Atlantis.  When they evacuated they couldn't bring a potentially powerful and dangerous life form back, so they left it there and took their research with them to continue along the ascension path in the Milky Way.  We do see Ancients taking their version of floppy discs with them when they evacuated in Before I Sleep.

Comment: Would you be interested in an email chain on this subject?